# simple_form custom input with content_for javascript head?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using a [datepicker](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/) and want to create a custom simple_form input

currently I'm doing this on EACH form:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/datepicker/master/dist/datepicker.min.css">
<script src="/datepicker/master/dist/datepicker.min.js"></script>

<%= simple_form_for(myobj) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :some_date, as: :string, input_html: {class: "datepicker", onchange: "this.form.submit();", autocomplete: "off"} %>
<% end %>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({format: "yyyy-mm-dd"});
  });
</script>
```

That gets annoying after the first time so i created a custom input:

```
# app/inputs/datepicker_input.rb
class DatepickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input(wrapper_options={})
    wrapper_options.symbolize_keys!
    wrapper_options[:input_html] ||= {class: 'datepicker', onchange: 'this.form.submit();', autocomplete: 'off'}
    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)

    template.content_for(:head) do
      [
        template.stylesheet_link_tag('https://rawgit.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/master/dist/datepicker.min.css'),
        template.javascript_include_tag('https://rawgit.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/master/dist/datepicker.min.js')
      ].join.html_safe
    end

    js = <<JS
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {$(".datepicker").datepicker({format: "yyyy-mm-dd"});});
</script>
JS

    template.content_for(:javascript) { js.html_safe }
    @builder.text_field(attribute_name, merged_input_options).html_safe
  end
end
```

which lets me do:

```
<%= simple_form_for(myobj) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :some_date, as: :my_datepicker %>
<% end %>
```

unfortunately it include the JS/CSS multiple times and have not found a decent solution to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Here is a simple_form datepicker custom input:

```
# app/inputs/datepicker_input.rb
class DatepickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input(wrapper_options={})
    wrapper_options.symbolize_keys!
    wrapper_options[:input_html] ||= {class: 'datepicker', onchange: 'this.form.submit();', autocomplete: 'off'}
    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)

    unless template.instance_variable_get(:@submitted_content_for_head)
      # prevents from being inserted twice
      template.instance_variable_set(:@submitted_content_for_head, true)
      template.content_for(:head) do
        [
          template.stylesheet_link_tag('https://rawgit.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/master/dist/datepicker.min.css'),
          template.javascript_include_tag('https://rawgit.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/master/dist/datepicker.min.js')
        ].join.html_safe
      end
    end

    unless template.instance_variable_get(:@submitted_content_for_footer)
      # prevents from being inserted twice
      template.instance_variable_set(:@submitted_content_for_footer, true)

      js = <<JS
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {$(".datepicker").datepicker({format: "yyyy-mm-dd"});});
</script>
JS

      template.content_for(:javascript) { js.html_safe }
    end

    @builder.text_field(attribute_name, merged_input_options).html_safe
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I would simply move CSS/JS files as well as JavaScript snippet in the main template, and not worry about adding those via custom input. Even compile them into the main CSS and JS file to avoid extra calls on page load.

Comment: Its wasteful to include the JS and CSS on every page load if only 1% of them visit a FORM with the included datepicker

Comment: Wasteful of what? Care to explain? If you wanna go that route, you might wanna look at jQuery itself. Obviously you are using it. How “wasteful” is to load entire jQuery on every page load when u use prob less than 10% of it.